# user\<myuser>\Deskop folder not showing all shortcuts from Desktop

Tags: windows, user-accounts, shortcuts, user, public-folders

I have windows 10, and I noticed that sometimes when I install some program, the shortcut is created but in the WRONG FOLDER!

After a program is installed, the shortcut is created and situated in `user\Public\Desktop` folder , and the `user\my user\Desktop` does not show this shortcut (THIS PC -> Desktop)

I never noticed this before.

So on the desktop I can see everything, but when I go in the folder user\Desktop I miss some shortcuts (created by programs I installed) which are in this folder  `user\public\Desktop`

One interesting thing I noticed that after some software installations (when is checked create shortcut on desktop) shortcut goes to `user\my user\desktop` folder and some installations place their shortcuts in `user\public\desktop` 
(e.g. notepad++, devc++ are creating their shortcuts correctly in my user desktop folder)

Why is this happening?

Can this be solved? Is there any solution?

I want that all the shortcuts created by programs that I install are present in `user\myuser\Desktop` and not in the public one.....

I did not noticed this in windows 7/8 when I was using them.

[image]

Comment: It has to do with the way that the installer was made. It can install for all users or just for the user running the install. If the installer is an MSI and properly written there should be a public property called ALLUSERS that you can specify at the command line to control this behavior.

Comment: The thing is that during all the installations , I am just asked  - >"create the shortcut on desktop"

and some installations creates their shortcut on public and some on current user ....

Is it possible to force somehow, so all the shortcuts get in User\Desktop folder?

Comment: That is because some installations default to installing for all users and some default to installing just for the user running the install. There is no global setting that controls this behavior. It is controlled by each individual install and how the software packager wrote it.

Comment: Ok, so it has nothing to do with windows ?

Comment: This may be an XY problem. Why exactly do you care if it goes to the public desktop? What issue does it cause for you?

Comment: There is no issue, I just noticed when I was looking at my user\desktop folder, that I miss shortcuts that are present on the desktop...
was wondering if they can go automatically in user\desktop fodler

Comment: Be sure you are running the installer as an Administrator.  I only mention this because you seem to have a knowledge gap when it comes to how installers work in Windows.

Comment: I already tried to run it also as administrator; but in this case there is no difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

As @EBGreen already mentioned in his comment, it depends on installer.

> Can this be solved? Is there any solution?

Simply move the shortcuts from the public Desktop folder to your personal one (drag / drop).

Comment: Yes of course drag drop works, but I mean , some solution in the way to change this , so they go automatically in user\desktop (maybe change some windows property or so) ?

Comment: There is no windows property that controls this behavior.

Comment: The installer can choose which folder.  Does it install for all users? Public/Desktop folder. Does it install just for you? your desktop folder. Of course, these folders will change in future versions of the OS.